# smali - error copying double parameter

Tags: android, smali, apktool

I'm fairly knew to using smali, so apologies if this is a beginners question.

I am using Apktool to turn an apk file into smali, with the aim being to insert logging calls into the code.

To do this, I have incremented .locals by one (to add a new register) then am trying to move all the register back to their original positions.

I have issues when trying to move parameters that use two registers (longs and doubles). If I include code to move them, the apk recompiles but does not open on an emulator. I'm not having this issue when moving other types.

For example, the below works fine. If I add `move-wide/from16 v6, p1` in line 68, the app will no longer open (the below is after I have incremented the .locals from 5).

```
.method public breakerTheSecond(JLjava/lang/String;)V
 59      .locals 6
 60      .param p1, "pk"    # J
 61      .param p3, "ab"    # Ljava/lang/String;
 62 
 63      .prologue
 64       move-object/from16 v8, p3
 65 
 66      move-object/from16 v5, p0
 67 
 68      
 69 
 70     .line 56
 71      const/4 v0, 0x1
 72 
 73      .local v0, "a":I
 74      const/4 v1, 0x2
 75 
 76      .line 58
 77      .local v1, "b":I
 78      invoke-virtual {v5}, Lcom/test/bbutton  
   /MyActivity;->getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;
 79 
 80      move-result-object v2
 81 
 82      const-string v3, "test"
 83 
 84      const/4 v4, 0x0
 85 
 86      invoke-static {v2, v3, v4}, Landroid/widget    
      /Toast;->makeText(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava
    /lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widg    et/Toast;
 87 
 88      move-result-object v2
 89 
 90      .line 59
 91      invoke-virtual {v2}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V
 92 
 93      .line 61
 94      return-void
 95  .end method
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Good question! Keep it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long and double values are referenced using only their first register. So when you do the `move-object/from16 v5, p0` on line 66, it is moving the entire double value from p0, p1 to v5, v6.

Referencing the second half of a 64-bit value isn't allowed, so when you try to do `move-wide/from16 v6, p1`, it sees that p1 is the second half of the value in p0, and gets grumpy with you :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It didn't solve my issue, but put me on track to the solution. My issue was that p1 was stored in v7 and v8 originally. Due to the ordering of my statements, v8 was overwritten before I had move p1(line 64). To fix this, I just moved `move-object/from16 v8, p3` after the the move-wide/from 16 statement.